# HPを作成中ですが、CSSとSCSSが反映されません。

Tags: css, html5, scss

**現象**
作成中のHPをVS CodeのLive Serverでプレビューとして見た。
CSSとSCSSが反映されない。

**期待値**
logo.svgを`width: 120px;`、`height: 40px;`に設定したい。

**再現手順**

下記のコードをGoogle Chromeで実行する。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ポートフォリオサイト1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="index.html" class="header__profile-button"><img src="image/logo.svg" alt="プロフィール"></a>
        <nav class="header__breadcrumb-trail">
                <a href="" class="header__breadcrumb-trail">About</a>
                <a href="" class="header__breadcrumb-trail">Bicycle</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

<!-- 省略 -->

</body>
</html>
```

header.scss

```
.header {
    .header__profile_button {
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;
    }
}
```

header.css（header.scssをコンパイルしたもの）

```
.header .header__profile_button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

下のURLのサイトを模写していました

https://code-step.com/demo/html/profile/

Answer (score 2):

基本的なことを確認しますが、
header.scssをコンパイルしてheader.cssは作れたのですか？

header.scss

```
.header {
    .header__profile_button {
            width: 120px;
            height: 40px;
    }
}
```

header.scssをコンパイルしてできたheader.css

```
.header .header__profile_button {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=header.css.map */
```

Comment: https://qiita.com/nakamurashun0621/items/b87c25943076bf59051c

上記URLを参考にしてCSSにコンパイルすることに成功しました。